# TSQL Query History Table MSSQL2008r2

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

MSSQL 2008r2

I'm trying to query a table that stores the start and end dates of changes and I want to return all the rows between two dates, a @StartDate and and @EndDate.

Here's the sample table schema

```
    CREATE TABLE dbo.History(
     cKey   INT NOT NULL
    ,vKey   INT NOT NULL
    ,CreateDate DATETIME NOT NULL
    ,DeletedTime    DATETIME NULL
)
```

So my query needs to include rows where the [CreateDate] is <= @StartDate but where the [DeletedTime] IS NULL, also where the [CreateDate] is <= @StartDate and [DeletedTime] is < @EndDate.

As the [DeletedTime] column is nullable so those rows where the [DeletedTime] is null are still current/active.

The following SQL doesn't work.  Only returns rows where the [DeletedTime] IS NULL, i.e. active rows.  Excluding those rows that were deleted between @StartDate and @EndDate

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.History 
WHERE @StartDate >= CreateDate 
AND @EndDate <= ISNULL( DeletedTime, '2099-12-12 23:59:59' )
```

Any ideas experts?
Thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this

```
WHERE (CreateDate <= @StartDate AND [DeletedTime] IS NULL) 
     OR ([CreateDate] <= @StartDate and [DeletedTime] < @EndDate)
```

Comment: Thanks but this is returning rows where the [DeletedTime] is before @StartDate

Comment: This looks to have done it.  `WHERE ( (CreateDate <= @StartDate AND DeletedTime IS NULL) 
     OR (CreateDate <= @StartDate and DeletedTime BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate) )
`

Comment: @Mountaineer : ah..Great!